# Chain rule for covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Does a chain rule for the covariant derivative exist so that we can evaluate an expression like
$$\nabla_c\sqrt{t_{ab}}?$$

where $t_{ab}$ are tensor components?

More generally, how do we take the covariant derivative of a function of tensor components $f(t_{ab})$, i.e.
$$\nabla_c f(t_{ab})?$$

Comment: $\sqrt{t_{ab}}$ are not components of a tensor so your expression is physically meaningless.

Comment: @G.Smith why exactly is it not a tensor

Comment: @Shashaank It doesn’t satisfy the transformation rule for a tensor with two covariant indices.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm thinking of taking the covariant derivative $\nabla_c \sqrt{g}$ where $g$ is the metric determinant. How can I use some sort of chain rule to take care of the square root?

Comment: Yes. The chain rule works for covariant derivatives. As far as I know, it works for any kind of derivative.

Comment: @octonion But you can define a covariant derivative on $\sqrt{g}$.

Comment: @BenceRacskó, How? It's not a scalar

Comment: @octonion it's a density, which can be covariantly differentiated

Comment: @BenceRacskó, Ok yes searching the topic I see you yourself have been interested in an extension of the definition of the covariant derivative to densities in the past: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267059/covariant-derivative-of-tensor-densities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chain rule if the object is a tensor formed by tensor products and contractions, for instance
$$\nabla_c (A^{bde}B_{bdf})=B_{bdf}\nabla_c A^{bde}+A^{bde}\nabla_c B_{bdf}.$$
Something like $f(t_{ab})$ is in general not a tensor so the action of the connection coefficient part of the covariant derivative is undefined on it.